# Can I apply Dropout In layers other than Fully Connected layers in CNN

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, dropout

I have read and seen that in CNN we apply *DROPOUT* layer between the *FULLY CONNECTED* layers to reduce overfitting.

Can we also apply the dropout layer between the *CONV* layers and the *POOL* layers. I have not seen models with this method applied. Will it help in overfitting when applied between these layers or are there any disadvantages to it?

Comment: See (own) answer in the SO thread [Does dropout layer go before or after dense layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701544/does-dropout-layer-go-before-or-after-dense-layer-in-tensorflow/47702111#47702111) and the links therein.

Answer (score 2):

In a CNN, each neuron produces one feature map. Since spatial dropout which is normally used for CNN's is per-neuron, dropping a neuron means that the corresponding feature map is dropped.

Pooling usually operates separately on each feature map, so it should not make any difference if you apply dropout before or after pooling.

Yes it should help with preventing overfitting. The added advantage is you can get uncertainty from the network at zero cost if using dropout.

Comment: By neuron do you mean a kernel filter? and do you mean dropout closes the output generated by that filter??

Comment: Yes, I do mean a kernel filter

Comment: Please can you explain your last line in detail ie. uncertainty from the network at zero cost.

Comment: There is a method called MC dropout  which https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02142.pdf explains. In this they add MC sampling at inference time which provides uncertainty.